# Create dictionary and replace by it latin words in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have  dataset with latin words

```
text<-c("TESS",
"MAG")
```

I want to set transliteration from latin-cyrillic

```
library(stringi)
d=stri_trans_general(mydat$text, "latin-cyrillic")
```

But I want to manually create the translit dictionary.
For example:

```
dictionary<-c("Tess"="ТЕСС"
"MAG"="МАГ"
.......
......
)
```

when dictionary is created,
in mydat$text,all latin words must be replaced by cyrillic words, which i set.
something like this

```
d=dictionary(mydat$text)
```

How perform such replacing?

## input

```
text<-c("TESS",
"MAG")
```

## file with translit

```
dict=path.csv
```

it containt

```
dict=

structure(list(old = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("mag", "tess"
), class = "factor"), new = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("маг", 
"тесс"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("old", "new"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

**#output**

```
text<-c("ТЕСС",
"МАГ")
```

that's all

Comment: something like `setNames(stri_trans_general(mydat$text, "latin-cyrillic"), mydat$text)` ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, where here my dictionary?

Comment: suppose. my dictionary in file dict.csv

Comment: It's not clear for me what you want, can you edit your post and state explicitly what is your exact input, and what would be your exact output ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, i edited post, please check

Comment: much better, but I need to add quotes around `тесс ` to trigger an error, and the data.frame I get has `тесс` and `TECC` as column names, and only one row, is it expected ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper тесс is not colnames,  i create old and new colnames ))) structure(list(old = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("mag", "tess"
), class = "factor"), new = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("маг", 
"тесс"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("old", "new"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)) I edited post))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181427/discussion-between-d-joe-and-moody-mudskipper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go!

```
dict <- structure(list(
  old = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("mag", "tess"),class = "factor"),
  new = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("маг", "тесс"), class = "factor")),
  .Names = c("old", "new"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

input<-c("TESS","MAG")

output <- with(lapply(dict,as.character), new[match(tolower(input),old)])
output
# [1] "тесс" "маг"
```

Comment: +1 for the `dput()` but — despite this working for the example — the columns should be `character` not `factor` as that could — in other contexts — cause problems.

Comment: It's more a comment to OP I guess, I just reproduced his data, but I agree that it'd be easier to start with characters. My solution works for both however.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, any trouble with your solution, can you check, what's wrong  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777989/create-dictionary-and-replace-by-it-latin-words-in-phrases-in-r