# Create dictionary and replace by it latin words in phrases in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr

Post similar with this
[Create dictionary and replace by it latin words in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687986/create-dictionary-and-replace-by-it-latin-words-in-r).
The solution of Moody_Mudskipper is good, but
let's examine this phrase

```
2049750 TESS чай солид     450mg
```

and so on...
indeed i must get

```
2049750 ТЕСС чай солид     450mg
```

but

```
output <- with(lapply(dict,as.character), new[match(tolower(input),old)])
output
```

after i get only NA.
What's wrong?

```
 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

_my dictionary

```
dict <- structure(list(
  old = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("mag", "tess"),class = "factor"),
  new = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("маг", "тесс"), class = "factor")),
  .Names = c("old", "new"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

## input

```
input<-("2049750 TESS чай солид     450mg")
```

## desired output

```
2049750 ТЕСС чай солид     450mg
```

## now i get output

```
1.Na
2.Na
...
35000 NA
```

Comment: How can you get so many `NA`s?

Comment: @AntoniosK, i have 35000 rows, so after work with dict, i get 35000 row with NA

Comment: Can you post samples of `new` and `old` using `dput()`?

Comment: @jdobres, i did it, please check

Comment: Why not posting the output you get when you excecute the example you posted? So, people that want to help can replicate the issue exactly...

Comment: And a reproducible input! :)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, i provided input:) please check

Comment: @AntoniosK , i provedid desired output and output which i get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
library(stringr)
dict2 <- setNames(toupper(as.character(dict$new)), 
                  paste0("\\b",toupper(dict$old),"\\b")) 
str_replace_all(input, dict2)
# [1] "2049750 ТЕСС чай солид     450mg"
```

Comment: can you do, that all number where more than 3 digits were remove?  So this 2049750 must be deleted.  and 450 must be left:)

Comment: If it's only at the start of the strings use `gsub("^\\d\\d\\d+? ","",input)` else search in the archive or ask new question ;)